# Downgrade Windows Phone 8.1 project to Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

I want to use parse library in my Windows Phone 8.1 application but it seems that they don't have support for it uptil now but they have it for Windows phone 8. Now I want to downgrade Windows Phone 8.1 project to Windows Phone 8 project. My application is in c#. I am unable to find any helpful resource or material related to it.

Please help.

Comment: what kind of library can works on WP8 but not on WP8.1?

Comment: The library probably works in Windows Phone Silverlight apps (8.0 or 8.1) but not in Windows Phone Runtime apps. There is no automated conversion between Windows Phone Silverlight and Windows Phone Runtime apps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are downgrading from **Silverlight 8.1** to **Silverlight 8.0**:
You can just create a new Silverlight 8.0 Project and copy over all your files from the 8.1 Project (there is no automated downgrade tooling).

If you want to go back from a **8.1 Store App** (Windows Runtime), you are out of luck. You can probably still copy most of you model/domain code over, but it will require a lot of rework.

In any case: If You used newer APIs, you will have to change those by hand of cause.

Is you want to change a **Portable Class Library**'s target, you can just right click the project in Solution Explorer and change the target frameworks.

Comment: I am asking about Windows Phone 8.1 not WinRT or silverlight.

Comment: @BilalAhmed The WP8.1 app can be *Silverlight* or *RunTime*, you probably have one of those two. KaiBrummund - your answer is wrong (at least in first paragraph) - some parts of API are available only from WP8.1 - BackgroundTask, StorageFile and so on - so you cannot copy all the files just like that, in some cases it will need other approach. Though, it is still easier to convert from WP8.1 SL than from WP8.1 RT.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Kai Brummunds answer, yes you are asking about Windows Phone however there are different types of Windows Phone application since the upgrade to 8.1 for instance you can have a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 application.

However I do not know of any automated process to downgrade. Most Windows 8 applications can be upgrade to 8.1, however I don't believe Microsoft would of put much effect into a downgrading process. Your only option would probably be to do this manually, but if you are using a standard Windows Phone 8.1 Application (non-silverlight), I imagine you will have alot of rework as quite alot of libraries were changed between 8 and 8.1 to improve the code reuse between Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot downgrade your Windows Phone 8.1 project to 8.0.
It is confirmed in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded a 8.0 project to 8.1 you could downgrade it back to 8.0:

Edit WMAppManifest.xml (View Code) and change XML namespace and AppPlatformVersion to

```xml
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2012/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.0">
```

Edit your csproj file and change TargetFrameworkVersion from 8.1 to 8.0

```xml
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v8.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```